# How to negate the @ symbol in a regular expression

Tags: regex

I have a file that I want to examine. Most of the numbers have the @ in front of them. I want to find all of the numbers that do NOT have the @ in front of them. They might have a space, or they might have another character. I don't know for sure, because I haven't found them yet.

So for this text

> First @30 line
>
> Second @40 line
>
> Find the four a4 line

I want to find the "4". The one with the "a" in front of it on the last line.

This sounded fairly simple, but using [RegEx101](http://regex101.com) or Notepad++ I am unable to perform the search.

I've tried `[^@]\d+`, but that finds the 30 and the 40 as well. I've tried `[^\@]\d+` with the same result. If I do `[^a]\d+` it correctly does not find the "a4". So it is clear the @ symbol is holding some special significance, but I cannot find any documentation regarding this.

How do I make this search?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that `3` is not `@`. You're searching for any character other than `@`, followed by any (non-zero) number of digits. `3` is a character other than `@`, and `0` is a non-zero number of digits. Hence a match.

You'd need to exclude digits as well as `@`: `[^@\d]\d+`.

Note: this still requires a character before the digits. You say you want any number of digits that isn't preceded by `@`. If a number is at the start of a line, it's not preceded by `@`. It's not preceded by any other character either though, so you'd need to adjust your regex to match.

A negative lookbehind works for that: `(?<![@\d])\d+`. This looks for `\d+`, except when preceded by `@` or another digit.

Comment: Or, y'know, `(^|[^@\d])`

Comment: @SeinopSys Sure. I think the negative lookbehind more directly corresponds to what the OP is asking, so may be easier to understand, but either would work.

Comment: Yes. That works. I'm feeling sort of dumb that I missed such an obvious mistake.